Applying penalty in difference calculations
I have a bunch of scores and would like to perform some basic calculations on the set. One such calculation includes determining the distance of each score between each other with an added penalty.
to explain the basic concept, I have values 0.51, 0.43, 0.81. As 0.51 and 0.43 are closer, the difference score should be relatively close while 0.51 is far from 0.81 and as such will have a greater penalty in the score.
I thought of using exponentials to perform such a task
the calculation is the
e ^ |value_1 - value_2|
code is python code
penalized_score = (np.e ** abs(a - b))

but I feel like there should be a better method

I have no idea what np.e ** abs(a - b) means.

sorry, I have updated the question to include what the code means. np.e is Napier's constant / Eular's number, abs is absoute value, and a,b are the values

OK. It seems to me that $f(|a-b|)$ will do, for any nonnegative and increasing function $f$; you could use $|a-b|$ or $|a-b|^2$ or $e^{|a-b|}$ etc., etc. The question is, what are you looking for? What properties would you like to see? You say there should be a better method than $e^{|a-b|}$, but you don't say what's wrong with the exponential, or what makes one method better than another.

I guess the best way to boil my question is how standard is what I am doing? I worry that this is not a standard practice for calculation differences while trying to include a penalty

In what context is it common for people to want to calculate differences while including a penalty? The only tag you've used is "discrete mathematics". I taught a course on discrete mathematics dozens of times, and the idea of calculating differences while imposing a penalty never came up in my lectures, or in any of the textbooks I consulted.

Are you still with us, linkey?

sorry, exchange didn't notify me the post received a new message. In high dimensional multiarray analysis for microarrays, We need to normalize the data and apply a cutoff to identify genes which are being modulated based on the changed conditions. Sometimes this is not as clear cut as based on the normalization method, genes changing can widely change. The approach I am looking into is using the standards found on the array, applying two different normalization methods and finally using difference to the controls as a way to measure activity.
